# Error in searching Google with Python 3.5 using bs4

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, ubuntu-16.04, google-search

I have been learning **Beautiful Soup** with Python 3.5 with this basic code to search **Google.com** .

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
 import urllib.request

 html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.google.com/search?q=python3')
 source = html.read()
 soup = BS( source , "lxml" )

 print(soup.prettify())
```

This is giving me an error : [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppRzh.png)

But by changing the URL with :

```
   html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.google.com/#q=python3')
```

It shows the correct output .

How is the URL changing the output of the code ? Is there any particular way of **Searching** google.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86 Safari/537.36'}
s = requests.get('http://www.google.com/search?q=python3',headers=headers)

soup =BeautifulSoup(s.content,'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

try this code, and i am sure this is what you are looking for

Comment: Why isn't it working with my code? What is the use of headers ?

Comment: The headers are to make google understand that you are not a program. But a browser

Comment: But I did not understand the difference between the URL's I am using to search on goolge ?

Comment: what url? the url is same

Comment: /search?q=python3   gives  error  while  /#q=python3 works fine ?